# Navigation view is hiding while pushing from SwiftUI views to Storyboard project in iOS13

Tags: swiftui, viewcontroller, navigationbar

I have added `SwiftUI` views in my existing swift project.
I have the following flow in the project

> FirstViewController --NavigationPush -> SwiftUIView1 -NavigationLink->
> SwiftUIView2 - NavigationLink-> SwiftUIView3 - NavigationLink
> (UIViewRepresentable) -> SecondViewController.

till SwiftUIView3 everything works as expected. while pushing from `SwiftUIView3 -> SecondViewController`, even though I'm setting the navigation property `isHidden = false`,
the navigationBar appears in the controller for a fraction of sec and disappears. I have tried to unhide navigation in all the controller life cycle methods. But nothing happens. Please let me know your suggestion to resolve this.

FYI, below code, I used `SwiftUI` to hide the navigation bar.
Code Block

```
.navigationBarTitle("") // This should be empty. 
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```